# MySQLi bind_param only works if all fields filled in

Tags: php, insert, mysqli

I made a PHP site that uses MySQLi with basic functionality to submit an HTML5 form into my database. The problem is that it will only insert into the database if ALL fields have been completed. How can I make it so that I can leave some fields blank, but have it work properly for the rest?

```
//connection statements above

$first=$_POST['first'];
$last=$_POST['last'];
$signed=$_POST['signed'];
$cardnumb=$_POST['cardnumb'];
$perm=$_POST['permcard'];

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO information (first_name, last_name, signed, number, permanent) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)");

$stmt->bind_param("sssss", $first, $last, $signed, $cardnumb, $perm);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

Just to be clear, this code works perfectly fine if ALL fields have been filled out. It DOES NOT work if a field is left empty.

Is there a way to make this work with empty fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't fill out the field does the `$_POST['varname'];` return `null` or an empty string?

If its an empty string this should still work fine.

If its `null` then it should work as long as the fields are allowed to be `null` in the database.

Check your table scheme and make sure the fields are allowed to be `null`.

Comment: It worked! I had this setup with without MySQLi which seemed to work regardless of whether or not NULL fields were allowed. I guess I never checked after changing to MySQLi.